# How to sum multivalued field with facet In Solr 5.2

Tags: solr, aggregation, facet

I use [JSON Facet API](http://yonik.com/json-facet-api/).

When I request faceting such as below.

```
facet: {
  depth1: {
    "method": "enum",
    "limit" : 30,
    "field" : "_srg9jrens_texts",
    "type" : "terms",
    "sort" : "index asc",
    "facet" : {
      "stats" : "sum(_45qotu8ef_doubles)"
    },
    "mincount" : 1
  }
```

It responses error message "can not use FieldCache on multivalued field: _45qotu8ef_doubles"

As you can see the field '_45qotu8ef_doubles' is multivalued==true.

> schema.xml

```
...
<dynamicField name="*_doubles" type="double" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true"/>
...
```

I need help to solve this problem especially I have to keep it as multiValued.

Please help!

Answer (score 0):

I use [Nested document](http://yonik.com/solr-nested-objects/) instead of using multivalued field.